# Update datatable with sub dropdowns (Dash Python)

Tags: python, callback, dropdown, plotly-dash

I am desperately looking for a way to make sub dropdowns. I'll explain.

I have a datatable, and I want to have different display parameters (like full, simplified and custom) : they are all 3 selected in a dropdown. But when custom is selected, I want a second dropdown to appear just under the first one in which I can select the specific rows I want.

Everything works except the way to hide/show this second dropdown. Because if I use one additional callback that display it if 'custom' is chosen, I have an error telling me that this dynamic dropdown does not exists. Does someone knows how to do it ? Thanks in advance ! The pseudo code used to show you this scenario :

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, dash_table
from dash_bootstrap_components import themes
from tools.visual import colors
import pandas as pd


data = [['A', 10, 19, 21], ['B', 15, 54, 12], ['C', 14, 5, 9], ['D', 14, 5, 9], ['E', 14, 5, 9]]
dashboard = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Mat', '1', '2', '3'])


app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[themes.BOOTSTRAP])


app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']}, children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(id='chosen-mat', multi=False, value='All',
                     options=['All', 'Custom'])
    ]),

    html.Div(id='custom-mat', children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(id='chosen-custom-mat', multi=True, value=[],
                     options=dashboard.iloc[0:, 0].to_list())
    ]),

    html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            data=dashboard.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in dashboard.columns],
            id='tbl')
    ], style={'margin-left': '20px', 'margin-right': '20px'}),

    html.Div(id='datatable-interactivity-container', style={'text-align': 'center'})
])


@app.callback(Output('tbl', 'data'),
              Output('tbl', 'columns'),
              Input('chosen-mat', 'value'),
              Input('chosen-custom-mat', 'value'))
def actualize_db(type_layout, mat_list):
    if type_layout == 'All':
        db = dashboard
    else:
        if mat_list is None:
            listt = []
        else:
            listt = mat_list
        db = dashboard[dashboard['Mat'].isin(listt)]
    return db.to_dict('records'), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in db.columns]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And what I need to do is this :

If CUSTOM selected :
[image]

If another option (here ALL) is selected :
[image]

Comment: You should provide your explanation with a piece of code!

Comment: You can provide a dummy code only for this specific example

Comment: So, it is kind of filtering the rows of table based on different selection of dropdown list?

Comment: Yes but this, I know how to do it, the thing I don’t is how to filter rows of table with a drop down that appears dynamically (depending on the choice in the previous drop down)

Comment: You can style your second dropdown with hidden attribute and control it by the first dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below code to Hide second dropdown when you choose `All` and show when you choose `Custom`. As you see, we will return children based on dropdown.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, dash_table
from dash_bootstrap_components import themes
import pandas as pd


data = [['A', 10, 19, 21], ['B', 15, 54, 12], ['C', 14, 5, 9], ['D', 14, 5, 9], ['E', 14, 5, 9]]
dashboard = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Mat', '1', '2', '3'])


app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[themes.BOOTSTRAP])


app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(id='chosen-mat', multi=False, value='All',
                     options=['All', 'Custom'])
    ]),

    html.Div(id='custom-mat'),

    html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            data=dashboard.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in dashboard.columns],
            id='tbl')
    ], style={'margin-left': '20px', 'margin-right': '20px'}),

    html.Div(id='datatable-interactivity-container', style={'text-align': 'center'})
])

@app.callback(Output('custom-mat', 'children'),
              [Input('chosen-mat', 'value')])
def hide_unhide(type_layout):
    if type_layout == 'Custom':    
        return dcc.Dropdown(id='chosen-custom-mat', multi=True, value=[],
                     options=dashboard.iloc[0:, 0].to_list())
    if type_layout == 'All': 
        return []

@app.callback(Output('tbl', 'data'),
              Output('tbl', 'columns'),
              Input('chosen-mat', 'value'),
              Input('chosen-custom-mat', 'value'))
def actualize_db(type_layout, mat_list):
    if type_layout == 'All':
        db = dashboard
    else:
        if mat_list is None:
            listt = []
        else:
            listt = mat_list
        db = dashboard[dashboard['Mat'].isin(listt)]
    return db.to_dict('records'), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in db.columns]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False,port='8051')
```

Comment: Hi ! First of all thanks for your reply. It helps but the only thing is that by doing that it only hides the options, but what I want to do is to hide the whole second drop down, not only the options… do you know how to do it ?

Comment: @CesarMaurey: Please check my updated answer.